# /etc/nfs.conf equivalent for Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, nfs, udp

What is the reason for `/etc/nfs.conf` not in Debian/Ubuntu?

There are `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` and `/etc/default/nfs-common`, but they aren't the same. They're used by `/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/nfs-utils_env.sh`, which also mentions `/etc/sysconfig/nfs`, but that's not the same as `/etc/nfs.conf`.

I wanted to add UDP support via `udp=y` in `[nfsd]` section in `/etc/nfs.conf`, which is not needed (it's enabled by default), but I'd still like to know why this file is not used.

Comment: Which specific Debian/Ubuntu versions and which nfs-utils versions are you asking about?

Comment: Talking about Debian. Version: anything recent version. But thanks to your question I found that Debian is still using `1.3.4` (see https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nfs-utils). Latest release is `2.4.3` and `nfs.conf` was added in `1.3.5-rc5` (as `nfs.config` at the time). I'm surprised that the package is that outdated (of course Ubuntu has the same version).

Comment: I have now the same problem. I wanna set `[nfsd]udp=y` in Ubuntu 20.04, but don't know where to set it, because the nfs.config isn't there.